# Turn Dictionary of Sets into Dictionary of Lists

Tags: python

Given the Dictionary of Sets:

```
{1: {2}, 2: {1, 3, 5}, 3: {2, 4}, 4: {3, 7}, 5: {2, 6}, 6: {5}, 7: {8, 4}, 8: {7}}
```

Is there anyway I can easily turn it into a Dictionary of Lists?

Desired Output:

```
{1: [2], 2: [1, 3, 5], 3: [2, 4], 4: [3, 7], 5: [2, 6], 6: [5], 7: [8, 4], 8: [7]}
```

Comment: What did you try and what doesn't work?

Comment: I tried changing the function where I built my dictionary of sets but in it I have default values. It won't let me set default values for the lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
result = {key: list(values) for key, values in dictionary.items()}
```

Comment: It's giving me the Error AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: Ah, you're using Python 3? Try `items()` instead.

Comment: Thanks I got it to work, I'm using Python 3 so items() did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Use dict comprehension and convert set to list using the list() function

```
a = {1: {2}, 2: {1, 3, 5}, 3: {2, 4}, 4: {3, 7}, 5: {2, 6}, 6: {5}, 7: {8, 4}, 8: {7}}
{k:list(v) for k,v in a.items()}
Out[274]: 
{1: [2],
 2: [1, 3, 5],
 3: [2, 4],
 4: [3, 7],
 5: [2, 6],
 6: [5],
 7: [8, 4],
 8: [7]}
```